# Strange output from Counting Sort in C

Tags: c

I have the following Counting Sort function

```
/*
 *File: countingSort.c
 *Description: A counting sort subroutine. Takes as input an array of integers.
 *             an array length and a range. All values in the input array must fall within                  [0, range].
 *            Takes O(range + arrayLen) time and O(range + arrayLen) extra space
 *
*/

#include "countingSort.h"

int* countingSort(int unsorted[], int arrayLen, int range) {
  int store[range + 1];
  int sorted[arrayLen];

  for ( int i = 0; i <= range; i++ ) {
    store[i] = 0;
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++ ) {
    sorted[i] = 0;
  }

  for ( int j = 0; j < arrayLen; j++ ) {
    store[unsorted[j]] ++;
  }

  for ( int i = 1; i <= range; i++ ) {
    store[i] += store[i-1];
  }

  for( int j = arrayLen - 1; j >= 0; j-- ) {
    sorted[store[unsorted[j]]] = unsorted[j];
    store[unsorted[j]] --;
  }

  return sorted;
}
```

The function is giving me really strange output. The output is nothing like the input most of the times but sometimes it just works. 
Why is this happening?

I am calling it from another file called cSortTest.c. 
That file looks like this

```
/*
 *File: cSortTest.c
 *Description: Tests countingSort.c
 *
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "countingSort.h"

int main() {
  int data[8] = { 2, 1, 9, 4, 4, 56, 90, 3 };
  int* p;

  p = countingSort(data, 8, 90);
  for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    printf("%d Element: %d\n", i, *(p+i) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a local array variable. This variable is destroyed when the function exits, making the address to it no longer safe or valid to access. In fact accessing it will give you what is called *undefined behavior*, which explains why it sometimes appears to "work".

This is a classic beginner's mistake in C. You must either have the caller pass in the desired destination array, or use `malloc()` to allocate "persistent" heap memory and return that:

```
int* countingSort(int unsorted[], int arrayLen, int range) {
  int *sorted = malloc(arrayLen * sizeof *sorted );
  if (sorted== NULL)
    return NULL;
  /* rest of sorting */
  return sorted;
}
```

The `arrayLen * sizeof *sorted` expression computes the number of bytes required for the allocation. There's no need to use `calloc()` which clears the memory; you're going to overwrite each element so clearing it is just wasted effort.

Comment: Should I use alloc()/calloc() for arrays as [this](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-calloc)  page seems to suggest